# Backbone Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a really simple backbone app, that returns:

```
undefined is not a function
```

in the console. Everything seems to be defined appropriately. Any idea what the issue could be?

js:

```
$(function () {

    var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        doStuff: function () {
            alert("doing Stuff");
        },
        doOtherStuff: function () {
            alert("doing other stuff");
        }
    });

    var myCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: "<button id='trigger'>Trigger</button>",
        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.collection.doStuff);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.collection.doOtherStuff);
            this.render();
        },
        events: {
            "click #trigger": "trigger"
        },
        render: function () {
            $("#app").html(this.template);
        },
        trigger: function () {
            alert("triggering");
            $(this).trigger("sync");
        }

    });

    var mymodel = new myModel({});

    var mycollection = new myCollection({
        model: mymodel
    });

    var mycollectionview = new myCollectionView({
            collection: mycollection
    });
});
```

Reproduced in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5C238/1/

Comment: Would the downvoter's care to comment why they are down voting an old question, appropriately asked, with an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling in the wrong order

```
<script src="//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//jashkenas.github.io/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LG38U/

Comment: great! I originally started this on jsbin and used their add a library function, until i got their `Error Script line(0)` function. I'll let them know their backbone lib isnt correct. thanks!